# Downloading earlier version of STS4

Tags: spring-tool-suite, spring-tools-4

STS 4 websites publishes link to download latest version of the IDE on their website.
How can we download one the earlier versions of STS ?

I am looking to download 4.3 as its having kotlin support.

PS: I am looking to import springframework code to eclipse(STS)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find previous versions of the Spring Tools 4 for Eclipse here: https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/wiki/Previous-Versions